# What was the standard size of a PC clone's badge indent?

Tags: ibm-pc, case, clone

Generic beige-box PC clones like [the ones pictured here](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=42661) often had an indent for the manufacturer's badge to be stuck on. Were these all a standard size, and if so, what were the dimensions?

Comment: It was _very important_ that they be 100% "PC compatible."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One inch square, I think (at least, the insets on my old, beige, midi-tower cases are).

Comment: Thanks! Looks like they're currently made as 25 × 25 mm with a 2 mm corner radius. I was blanking on what these were called, and it seems the term is [Case Badge](https://www.case-badges.com/domed-case-badges-with-your-logo-or-image-p-180.html)

Answer (score 8):

Measurements of my IBM Model 5150 indicate the badge itself is 1 in. square, equivalent to 25 mm. But there is an additional approximately 1/32 in. added for the indent area, thus allowing the badge to completely reside within the indent.

For "clones", I suppose the ones deemed "100% PC Compatible" would need to match this size, precisely.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen on this picture of a Selectric typewriter the badge there is very similar.

My guess would be that it was as simple as "We need a place for the IBM badge".

[image]